# Homebrew Mac Update Issues

Tags: macos, homebrew

This is something that I've noticed starting about 2 days ago. In my past experience, Homebrew would always have daily updates. I would always type the command `brew update` and voila, there would be packages that would be updated/deleted and Homebrew would display what changed. I also noticed that if I didn't update Homebrew for more than a day, I would get the following notice:

> Homebrew hasn't been updated in the last 24 hours. That's a long time in brew land. Type 'brew update.

However, the last time I updated Homebrew on my Mac was on August 10, 2016. Today is August 14, 2016 and when I type `brew update`, it tells me that everything is already up-to-date, even though I haven't updated Homebrew in 4 days. The update notice in `brew doctor` also does not show-up. I have not modified Homebrew in any way throughout this whole debacle.
**Is there a solution to this Homebrew updating issue or does Homebrew not have daily updates anymore?**

Comment: Since August 14, 2016, the latest version of Homebrew supports the command `brew update --force`, thanks to the merge of [this commit](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/commit/24fb0068e7933bec7e74a632fce3c4d3d05559c4). If an update issue like this ever happens again, you can just pass `--force` to `brew update` instead of copying that long `cd`/`git` command.

Answer (score 106, accepted):

According to https://github.com/Homebrew/brew#update-bug

If Homebrew was updated on Aug 10-11th 2016 and brew update always says Already up-to-date. you need to run

```
cd $(brew --repo); git fetch; git reset --hard origin/master; brew update
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.Really useful answer!

Comment: We can now use `brew update --force` instead of having to remember/copypaste this whole line :)

Comment: Thanks, this solved the problem nicely and I'm now happily back to my daily brew update dosage (`brew update --force` as suggested by @dominicbri7 did not work for me however, perhaps the brew version I started with was to old for that feature).

Comment: Thanks for this answer and the proper explanation. This is the answer.

Answer (score 4):

Homebrew is basically a git directory, so you can cd into the directory and perform a `git fetch` followed by a `git pull`

If you are on default config:

`cd /usr/local && git pull origin master`

Answer (score 1):

**Please run to debug what happens when update**

`brew update --debug --verbose`

`brew update --force`

My reference from this [comment](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/issues/895#issuecomment-245689516)